# Hyperbolic Geometry - Parabolic Matrix?

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

In lecture we defined for hyperbolic geometry using the Lorentz model on the upper sheet of the two sheeted hyperboloid:
$$Para_x=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 + \frac{x^2}{2} & -\frac{x^2}{2} & x\\
    \frac{x^2}{2} & 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} & x \\
    x & -x & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $Para$ stands for Parabolic.

For the sake of context, as an exercise (non assessed) we were asked to show that $Para_x \in O^{+}(1, 2)$, where $O^{+}(1, 2)=\left\{A|a_{11}>0, A^{T}JA=J\right\}$, $a_{11}$ is the first entry of the matrix $A$ and 
$$J=\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

My question is, what exactly is this $Para_x$? I've tried searching online for more information but I can't find this matrix defined anywhere. In case it helps, I've inputted this matrix into WolframAlpha, so some properties of the matrix can be found [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2B%28x%5E2%2F2%29%2C-x%5E2%2F2%2Cx%7D%2C%7Bx%5E2%2F2%2C1-x%5E2%2F2%2Cx%7D%2C%7Bx%2C-x%2C1%7D%7D).

Comment: Better tags for this would also be appreciated if any such tags exist.

Comment: This is the general form for a parabolic element of the Lorentz group.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It turns out that my searches should have contained "Lorentz" instead of "hyperbolic".